# I cannot find some the software I want in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my PC (Fresh)

I tried to install some software I wanted from Ubuntu Software Center but some of them were not found.

It shows this error:

> "There isn’t a software package called “gimp” in your current software
> sources."
>
> updating cache
>
> Querying softwares sources

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

Did you use the following commands in the Terminal after you freshly installed your Ubuntu. (If you did not do it now)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then search again in the Ubuntu Software Center. If you still can't see the software try this in the Terminal >>

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: i don't install any softwear on softwear center

Comment: Did you try the commands I pasted above? what were the results?

Comment: Most of the times, I got the same issue and only way to get past it is to either install the offline way by tar balls or threw the name I got threw online install in the way this answer mentioned. :)

Comment: Gimp has to be there! Have you by any chance disabled any of the repositories that come by default?

Comment: I've had this too, must be a bug.

Comment: me three, same here!